# How to remove \r\n from output in Scrapy in command prompt?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am scraping pages of a website. Whenever I try to scrape `Regional_subcategories`. I get `\r\n` with many spaces. How to remove it?

Here is the image: [image]

Here is my code :

```
def Regional_category(self, response):
    names = {'name1':'Regional_subcategories',
             'name2':'Related_Categories',
             'name3':'Site title',
             'name4':'Site Description',
             }
    finder = {'finder1': '.browse-node::text',
              'finder2': '.one-browse-node::text',
              'finder3': '.site-title::text',
              'finder4': '.site-descr::text',
              }
    yield from self.find_items(response, names, finder)
```

Comment: Try `string_.strip()`

Comment: Where to write?

Answer (score 3):

Try [`str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip):

```
>>> s = '\r\n      text\r\n    '
>>> print(s.strip())
text
```

if you have a list of strings from which you want to remove whitespace you can use list comprehension:

```
>>> li = ['\r\n      text\r\n    ', '\r\n      text2\r\n    ']
>>> li2 = [st.strip() for st in li]
>>> li2
['text', 'text2']
```

Comment: ```for name, find in zip(names.values(), finder.values()):
      items[name] = response.css(find.strip()).extract()
      yield items```                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                      
               I have added ```strip()```. Why it's not working now?

Comment: @BilalKhan what is the error you are getting? Please add the code of your comment and the error message to your question.

Comment: Although I edited it but I am getting the same ```\r\n``` without any error. Why strip is not working?